# SQL Query parent-child in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm facing a problem trying to build a query. What im trying to do is to select all that dont have parent or have parent but only the latest created (the parent itself are not included in the selection). Can someone help me on this? Im using postgresql 12.

*For an example, i have these table here :*

```
| id | parent id | date_created | payment_uid |
| -- | --------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| 1  |           |  2022-03-10  |<random_uid >|
| 2  |           |  2022-03-11  |<random_uid >|
| 3  |           |  2022-03-12  |<random_uid >|
| 4  |    1      |  2022-03-13  |<random_uid >|
| 5  |    1      |  2022-03-14  |<random_uid >|
| 6  |    3      |  2022-03-15  |<random_uid >|
```

*and the result after selection should be :*

```
| id | parent id | date_created | payment_uid |
| -- | --------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| 2  |           |  2022-03-11  |<random_uid >|
| 5  |    1      |  2022-03-14  |<random_uid >|
| 6  |    3      |  2022-03-15  |<random_uid >|
```

p/s: im new to sql query..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM myTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        parent_id, MAX(date_created) date_created
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY parent_id
) b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id AND a.date_created = b.date_created
```

`NULL` parent with max date

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM myTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(parent_id, 0) parent_id, MAX(date_created) date_created
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY COALESCE(parent_id, 0)
) b ON COALESCE(a.parent_id, 0) = b.parent_id 
    AND a.date_created = b.date_created
```

All the `NULL` with have parent with last created

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM myTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        parent_id, MAX(date_created) date_created
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY parent_id
) b ON (a.parent_id = b.parent_id AND a.date_created = b.date_created)
    OR a.parent_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but this query didnt select those with null parents.. i still need the null parent as well..

Comment: @SyahrulezAnuar `NULL` parent with the max date?

Comment: basically want to select `NULL` parent and if they have parent, select max date created (does not include parent in selection)

Comment: @SyahrulezAnuar Added one more query, try it and let me know.